# Extracting specific words using regexp

Tags: regex

I was trying to extract words that are surrounded by `*` from a string using regular expressions, such as the string `*sample*`, where I want to extract `sample`, but I'm unable to make correct regexp.

I tried the following regexp `[*]{1}.*[*]{1}, ^[*]{1}.*[*]{1}$?`, but it isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the following example:

```
this is a *sample* string, but not *really*
```

The following will match `sample* string, but not *really` in the first captured group:

```
\*(.*)\*
```

While the following will match `sample` as the first captured group:

```
\*([^*]*)\*
```

Comment: I'd go for this one. If your regexes support shy matching, an alternative formulation for the latter would be `\*(.*?)\*`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this regex

```
(?<=\*).*(?=\*)
```

If your programming language supports lookbehind and lookahead. If you want to match minimum possible text between two `*`s then you can go for the lazy quantifier like this

```
(?<=\*).*?(?=\*)
```

Comment: What will that do with `"*this*that*"` or `"*this* and *that*"`?

Comment: @muistooshort Yes it is a greedy quantifier, it matches as much as is possible between two `*`s. Included the lazy quantifier also just to make it clear.

Answer (score 0):

The first one works fine for me.  You could just add a capturing group in parentheses:

```
[*]{1}(.*)[*]{1}
```

However, this is very verbose.  You can just do:

```
\*(.*)\*
```

You escape * with \ because it's a special character.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
\*[^*]*\*
```

This means `\*`: *, `[^*]*?` 0 or more non-*, `\*`: *

http://gskinner.com/RegExr?2v0e4

Now, if you don't want to "extract" the `*`, you can do this:

```
(?:\*)([^*]*)(?:\*)
```

This will put only the text in a capturing group (the `( )` part) and put the `*` in non capturing groups (the `(?: )` part)